# Having issues aligning logo with H1 and H2 in header

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out why my logo img is leaking into my navigation and not aligning. I need the logo to align with the h1 and h2 in my header. It currently looks like this:
[image]

Here is my html:

```
<body>
  <div id="headerWrapper">
    <header>
      <img src="images/logopracticedone.png" alt="">
      <h1>Science Museum</h1>
      <h2>A Celebration of Technology & Mechanics</h2>
    </header>
  </div>
  <div id="navWrapper">
    <nav class="clearfix">
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Visit Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">See and Do</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Learning</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

Here is my SCSS:

```
body {
    font-family: $fontFamily;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: $regularWeight;
}


header {
    img { max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    float: left;}
    
    padding: 1rem $gutter;

    h1 {
        margin: 0; 
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        font-weight: $semiBold;
        
    } //end of h1
    h2{
        margin: 0; 
        font-size: 1.2rem; 
        font-weight: $regularWeight;
    } //end of h2

} //end of header
```

Comment: Your img is floated. If you're insisting on using floats you'll need to do a clear to force flow back to being sequential.

Comment: I would suggest using flexbox instead of floats, for your header layout.

Answer (score 0):

- Remove float from `img`
- Adjust the `height` in css of `img` to fit according to your design.
- Move the headings into a div to cover for removing that float.
- Make `display` `inline-block` for both the new `div` and `img`

```html
<img src="images/logopracticedone.png" alt="">
<div>
  <h1>Science Museum</h1>
  <h2>A Celebration of Technology & Mechanics</h2>
<div>
```